# Dictionary data sets in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to create sets in a dictionary in python to iterate over like this:

```
scenarioSets = {[{'a': '55','b': '66', 'c': '77'},
               {'a': '11', 'b': '22', 'c': '33},
               {'a': '44', 'b': '55', 'c': '66'}]}

 for letters,values in scenarioSets.items():
       StringQuery1 = letters + '=' +  values
       StringQuery2 = letters + '=' +  values
       StringQuery3 = letters + '=' +  values

       do something with this set...
```

Where Strings should return value sets like this: 
1. 'a=55' 'b=66' 'c=77',
2. 'a=55' 'b=66' 'c=77',
3. 'a=55' 'b=66' 'c=77',  I need to be able to use the key and the value.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you have a dict of dicts or a list of dicts or a set with a list of dicts which is impossible?

Comment: list of dicts I guess.  It seems more like dictionary sets to me.  I'm using this format from a javascript script.  I don't know how to translate it exactly in python-  I am new to python

Comment: well sets cannot have dicts or lists inside a set, so it must be a list of dicts or there is something missing

Comment: OK. I would like the syntax to iterate over a list of dicts?  How does one do that so that i get the whole dict a,b and c then move to the next dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scenarioSets = [{'a': '55','b': '66', 'c': '77'},
               {'a': '11', 'b': '22', 'c': '33'},
               {'a': '44', 'b': '55', 'c': '66'}]

for d in scenarioSets:
    for k,v in d.items():
        print("key = {} values = {}".format(k,v))
key = a values = 55
key = c values = 77
key = b values = 66
key = a values = 11
key = c values = 33
key = b values = 22
key = a values = 44
key = c values = 66
key = b values = 55
```

Comment: Thanks!  I needed that 2nd for loop.

Comment: no worries, was not sure if we were on the same page or not, glad it helped.